# ArrayFormula with sum of previous rows

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have an ArrayFormula to calculate a value for each row, and for each 6th row I want it to calculate the sum of the previous 5 instead.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18g2bOOBqsUgmy3ZXINOl6hcaMXf-uYJv7PGft247FjU/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried several routes, including google script, but keep banging my head against limitations of ArrayFormula.

Comment: What your mean? Value of each row in previous 5 instead is number of row or any other value

Comment: Row number is just an example. So five rows with calculated values and then a sum row yes

Answer (score 0):

**You need make group by rows**

**My E.g**

Cell A2 (Name groups):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B<>"",FLOOR((ROW(A2:A)-2)/5)+1,""))`

---

Column B (Your Data)

---

Cell E2 (Result):

`=QUERY({QUERY({A2:B},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1>0 group by Col1");
         QUERY({A2:B},"select Col1,Col2 where Col1>0")},
  "select Col2 where Col1>0 order by Col1,Col2 label Col2 ''")`

---

[image]

**Function References**

- [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)